# Android Kotlin findViewById(R.id.txt_email) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a student , so i am a beginner and i did found this question here but i didn't understand what to do to solve this in my code
as you can see it's a simple code for someone who know kotlin
i just want to start the signup activity when i press the button signUp

This is the mainActivity code:

```
package com.example.myclass

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var txtEmail: TextView
    private lateinit var edtEmail: EditText
    private lateinit var txtPassword: TextView
    private lateinit var edtPassword: EditText
    private lateinit var btnContinue: Button
    private lateinit var btnSignUp: Button
    private lateinit var btnFcb: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        txtEmail=findViewById(R.id.txt_email)
        edtEmail=findViewById(R.id.edt_email)
        txtPassword=findViewById(R.id.txt_password)
        edtPassword=findViewById(R.id.edt_password)
        btnContinue=findViewById(R.id.btn_continue)
        btnSignUp=findViewById(R.id.btn_signup)
        btnFcb=findViewById(R.id.btn_fcb)

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            val intent=Intent(this,signUp::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML code for the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blue_ligth"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="464dp"
        android:layout_height="164dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_backgound"
        android:hint="MyClass@gmail.com"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blue_ligth"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_backgound"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:hint="●●●●●●●●●●●●●●"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blue_ligth"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:text="continue"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_ligth"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_backgound"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:text="sign up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_fcb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bt2_3_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:text="login with facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

This is the error in the image:
[image]

This is the code with the error:
[image]

This is the code of the error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myclass, PID: 17363
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myclass/com.example.myclass.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myclass.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another layout called activity_main? Sometimes two layouts are created for vertical and horizontal orientation.

Comment: Yes, if you have two versions of the same layout, you probably want to ensure all the same view IDs are in both.

Comment: it's time to use ViewBinding

Comment: @lyncx how can i check it

Comment: val txtEmai: TextView=  find(R.id.txt_email)  jusr tryb this way may be it work

Answer (score 2):

Please look into "viewBinding". It'll hardly take 15mins(maybe less) to implement it in your project. It was created to solve these kind of problems

This time is on me...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //To add
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //To add
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        //To remove
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        txtEmail=findViewById(R.id.txt_email)
//        edtEmail=findViewById(R.id.edt_email)
//        txtPassword=findViewById(R.id.txt_password)
//        edtPassword=findViewById(R.id.edt_password)
//        btnContinue=findViewById(R.id.btn_continue)
//        btnSignUp=findViewById(R.id.btn_signup)
//        btnFcb=findViewById(R.id.btn_fcb)

        binding.btnSignup.setOnClickListener {
//            val intent= Intent(this,signUp::class.java)
//            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

Every time you want to use a view, just call
[ binding."Your_view_id_here" ]

Don't forget to add this in you build.gradle (module) file

```
android{
 //...

   buildFeatures {
       viewBinding true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to check.

1. Check that a view with an ID of `txt_email` actually exists in your layout file.
2. Check that you did not mistakenly import an ID with the same name from another layout file. You can easily confirm this by looking at your import lines. Check that you're not importing an ID from a totally different fragment.

Also, I think you should take time out to learn about DataBinding and ViewBinding. It's a cheap way to avoid situations like this.